# assertion failure for table cell

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm getting this error:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UITableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2903.2/UITableView.m:5251
```

But it shouldn't happen since I've already declared the cell identifier in the storyboard:

[image]

This is my code:
[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the complete error message?

Comment: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier personalCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

Comment: You haven't registered your nib for the cell.  See registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:.

Comment: (Or don't use the `forIndexPath:` flavor of that method.)

Comment: I'm using storyboard. I don't think I need to register a nib file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Restoration ID is not the same as Reuse Identifier. You should enter the Reuse Identifier as shown in the picture below instead of the Restoration ID.

[image: Reuse Identifier is entered here]

Comment: god @!@$! it was hidden